# iPhone App Crashes When trying to play video

Tags: xcode, video

I'm trying to get a simple view based app to play a video, but it crashes, heres my code,

```
 - (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {

   NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"mov"];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];

    mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
     [mpc setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

     [[self view]addSubview:mpc.view];

     [mpc setFullscreen:YES];


      [mpc play];
      }
      @end
```

and here is where it takes me in xcode when it fails

```
 //
 //  main.m
 //  video_play
 //
 //  Created by nathaniel harman on 20/04/2013.
 //  Copyright (c) 2013 machupicchumobile. All rights reserved.
 //

 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 #import "VideoPlayAppDelegate.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([VideoPlayAppDelegate           class]));
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

```
NSString *audio=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:audio];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this like, where you will find the code I'm using for playing the movie or video.

http://kiranjasvanee.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/play-video-or-movie-in-iphone/?preview=true&preview_id=3&preview_nonce=cf5d01de8d

Let me implement this code here, so can review it,

First you have to import the MediaPlayer header library to use it’s MPMoviePlayer for playing any movie or video.
You can import this library in .h or .m view controller – depends upon where you declaring your MPMoviePlayerViewController object.

Library import:-

```
#import MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h
```

Object declaration:-

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer;
```

implement this below code in .m file, when play movie pressed:-
below used Movie_URL identifier contains the URL of video or movie.

```
- (IBAction)BtnVideoShowCalled:(id)sender 
{ 
// Put your Navigation and Tabbar related code here. 
Ex :- /* self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES; */ 

//If you wanna play a video from tableview, then assign tag to _btn and add target this function to that _btn. Ex :-
/* 
//Where, record is a object of Messages class.
NSInteger tid = [sender tag];
*/

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Movie_URL]];

    if(URL)
    {
        Class mplayerControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"MPMoviePlayerViewController");
        if(mplayerControllerClass != nil) {
            moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:URL];
            moviePlayer.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
            [moviePlayer shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:YES];
            if(moviePlayer)
            {
                [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
            }
           [movieplayer readyPlayer];
        }
    }

}
```